# What is the best way to hide daffodil leaves after the flowers die?

Tags: leaves, bulbs, daffodils

I have an old flower bed in which the large daffodil clumps bloom spectacularly each spring, but after the flowers fade,  the leaves grow some and last for a couple of months before they also die. They aren't very attractive. What is the best method to disguise or hide them? Here are some options I've looked into:

- plant throughout the daffodils a similar leaved plant that flowers during the time the leaves of the daffodils are up
- plant various narrow leaved clump forming plants in with the daffodils for some variety
- cut the leaves off at ground level (I've heard this damages the next seasons blooms)
- flatten the leaves onto the ground and grow annuals through them
- plant something tall in front of them

I've discovered all of these methods, but don't know which one is most natural looking.

Comment: Regarding cutting off at ground level: I get annoyed that my parents don't put daffodils in a bed, they grow among the grass at the edge of the lawn. They get mowed when they start to die back and it hasn't harmed them yet (apart from when you accidentally mow them when they are growing and they come up with brown tips!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I plant hostas with daffodils. They leaf out later and cover the foliage of the daffodils as they die back.

My psychic gardening powers tell me you have some Regal Blue Hosta which could be split and planted with your daffodils.  Why not give it a try?

EDIT: Daffodils need full sun and Regal Blue Hosta are normally comfortable with half sun. So it depends on the location.
These hosta take [full sun](http://gardening.about.com/od/perennials/qt/Sun_Hosta.htm)

- Yellow Hosta: August Moon, Gold Regal, Golden Sculpture Rising Sun, Squash Casserole, Sum and Substance, Sun Power
- Yellow Variegated Hosta: Gold Standard, Inniswood, Regal Splendor, Sundance
- Fragrant Hosta: H. plantaginea, Aphrodite, Fragrant Bouquet, Fried Green Tomatoes', Guacamole, Honeybells, Invincible', Royal Standard, Summer Fragrance, So Sweet, Sugar & Cream
- White Variegated Hosta: H. undulata Albomarginata, Francee, Minuteman, Patriot
- Green Hosta: Invincible, Pearl Lake

If hosta are getting too much sun you will see

- Browning on the tips or outside edges of leaves
- Dull color or faded spots on leaves

Nice thing about hosta is that they are rugged plants that can be transplanted anytime in the growing season.  Mix and match and see how it goes!